# How to answer the question "what is the domain of this function"?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

Could you please help me understand and solve this problem about domain of function?

All that is written for the question is:

> What is  the  domain of this function? 
>   $$
> 2\sin\sqrt{2x-1}+1
> $$

Thanks.

Comment: $2x-1\ge 0$ would suffice

Comment: What the question means is "what is the subset of $\mathbb{R}$ on which the function is well-defined".

Comment: In which Swapnil's answer is still technically correct.  "all $x$ such that $2x-1\geq 0$ is true" counts as a "set" oficially.  If you prefer it appear in a different format, such as an interval of the form $[a,b)$, you can convert the equation $2x-1\geq 0$ into $x\geq \frac{1}{2}$ and then $x\in[\frac{1}{2},\infty)$

Comment: Thank you all for your answers; they're all great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the following

- $x\mapsto 2x+1$ is always defined.
- $x\mapsto \sin x$ is defined for all $x$.
- $x\mapsto \sqrt{x}$ is defined if and only if $x\geqslant0$.

Your function is a combination of them, thus you should see when the expression inside the radical is positive, i.e. for which $x$ is it true that $2x-1\geqslant0$. The domain of your function is then the set of solutions to that inequality.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $\sqrt{y}$ is defined for $y\ge 0$. So $2x-1\ge 0$ is the domain of the function. (as $\sin$ is defined on whole $\mathbb{R}$)

Answer (score 1):

We want to define the domain of the function to be as large as possible.  Note that $\sqrt x$ is defined over $x \ge 0$ only.  The $\sin$ function is defined over all the reals.  So the only restriction we have on the domain is that $2x-1 \ge 0$.